# Categorising "group by" groups by their contents

Tags: sql, join, grouping

I have a view which is a product of two joined tables:

```
ID Type
1   A
2   A
2   B
3   B
```

There can only be two values in Type column: A or B.

I would like to aggregate IDs into three categories: Catgegory_A, Category_B and Category_AB. If the ID is associated only with type A, it is assigned Category_A, if the ID is associated with types A and B it is associated with Categry_AB. Based on these rules, the view above should be categorised as follows:

```
ID  Category
1  Category_A
2  Category_AB
3  Category_C
```

Is it possible to write an SQL query to achieve this?

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Wouldn't the names more naturally be `A`, `AB`, and `B`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would name them differently, but the logic is:

```
select id,
       (case when min(category) = max(category)
             then 'Category_' || min(category)
             else 'Category_AB'
        end)
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: What is `'Category_' || min(category)`? It doesn't work in SQL Server.

Comment: Instead of `'Category_' || min(category)` use `concat('Category_', min(category))`.

Comment: @JohnyL . . . `||` is the *standard* SQL operator for string concatenation.  SQL Server uses the non-standard `+` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Independently of Gordon's answer, I came up with the following...

```
SELECT ID,
       CASE
           WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN 'AB'
           ELSE MAX(Type)
       END AS Category
FROM Products
GROUP BY ID
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7323b/3) to run :)